# Prove that no order can be defined on the complex numbers. (Baby Rudin: chapter 1 question 8)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Definition**

> An ordered field is a field $F$ which is also an ordered set, such that:
>   (i) $x+y < x+z$ if  $x$,$y$,$z \in F$ and $y<z$
>   (ii) $xy > 0$ if $x \in F$, $y \in F$, $x > 0$, and $y>0$

**Question**

> Prove that no order can be defined in the complex field that turns it into an ordered field. *Hint:* -1 is a square

**My approach**

To prove that there can be no order defined in the complex field, I used the second point of the definition.

Let $x=(0,1)$ and $y=(0,1)$.
I state that $x>0$ and $y>0$ (but I am unsure if I can do that).
Thus $xy$ should be strictly positive, yet $xy= i^2=-1 <0$, thus this disproves the fact that it is possible to define an order in the complex field.

Would this be an acceptable proof? Can I really state that $x=(0,1)>0$?

Comment: you can say: suppose that there is an order in $\Bbb C$ such that $i>0$ and $\Bbb C$ is an ordered field. But you can see that this order cannot be extended to the standard order on $\Bbb R$ because $i^2<0$. The proof is not complete or sufficient. You can complete the proof showing that when $i<0$ it doesnt define either an ordered field in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either prove that $x > 0$ or assume that and then assume that $x < 0$. For example, you would write:

> Assume $x > 0$ then $x^2 = xx > 0$ by (ii). Now assume that $x < 0$. Then $-x > 0$ (Prop. 1.18(a)) and again $x^2 = (-x)(-x) > 0$. In both cases we see that if $x \ne 0$ then $x^2 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$1=1\times 1$

Hence $1$ is a square so it's greater than $0$,

So $-1+0<-1+1$, so $-1<0$ but $i^2=-1$, so $-1$ must be greater than $0$, hence a contradiction.

Note that a square is greater than zero can be easily verified from the axioms.